# Filter DEM image collection for elevation band value greater than 0, to show land only - Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, dem, elevation, filter, visualisation

I'm trying to display only the land areas of a DEM image collection, by filtering the image collection for values greater than 0. I am not sure how to write the arguments properly. There is only 1 band in my image collection, that is elevation, 'b1'.

```
var land = dtm.filter(ee.Filter.greaterThan('b1', 0));
Map.addLayer(land, {min: 0, max: 2400, palette: ['000FFF', '57874d', 'e2dba7', 'fcc573', 'b69c8d', 'ffffff']}, 'dtm');
```

Comment: Do you wish to produce a binary raster where values >0 = 1 and all other values = 0? Or do you wish to mask values so that only pixel values >=0 are displayed in the map (i.e. all values <0 are assigned NoData)?

Comment: Just to mask it for visualisation/display purposes

Comment: @Aaron, Actually, I am not sure - this is only for visualisation purposes.  I want to use a colour palette that stretches over the land elevations (gt 0.), and I want the sea area (lte 0) to be blue. Now, I can't specify the right boundary between sea and land, using the colour ramp. I don't need land as a separate raster, if there is another way to display the land colour ramp over just the elevations > 0. But if it has to be a separate raster (image collection?) to achieve this, then that would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have solved this! I defined a function to mask out the water, then mapped it over the image collection. This gives a pretty good representation of the land-sea boundary.

```
//////////////// DEFINE FUNCTION ////////////////
  // Function to mask out water
  var S2maskedWater = function(image) {
   var land = image.select(['b1']);
    return image.updateMask(land.gt(0)).rename('land');
  };

//////////////// APPLY FUNCTION TO THE IMAGE COLLECTION ////////////////
// Apply water masking functions to image collection
var dtm_land = dtm.map(S2maskedWater);
print(dtm_land)


//////////////// USER INTERFACE ////////////////
Map.addLayer(dtm_land, {min: 0.1, max: 1600, palette: ['57874d', 'e2dba7', 'fcc573', 'b69c8d', 'ffffff']}, 'dtm');
```

[image]

Comment: Kindly accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to get the `min` and `max` values dialed-in properly to visualize the results. This example uses a Reducer to get the max value of the DEM, then automatically inserts that value into the `Map` parameters.

```
// Generate a polygon AOI
var poly = 
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-124.70093412636813, 50.12155750194576],
          [-124.70093412636813, 50.1046048653413],
          [-124.67381162880953, 50.1046048653413],
          [-124.67381162880953, 50.12155750194576]]], null, false);

// Use SRTM DEM as an example
var dataset = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');

// Clip dataset to AOI
var elevation = dataset.select('elevation').clip(poly);

// Get the maximum elevation value in DEM
var maxValue = elevation.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.max(), poly).get('elevation');

// Map results and automatically update the max value
Map.addLayer(elevation, {min: 0, max: maxValue.getInfo(), palette: ['000FFF', '57874d', 'e2dba7', 'fcc573', 'b69c8d', 'ffffff']}, 'elevation');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the problem I was having is visible here too - you see it doesn't give a clear edge between land and sea. That was why I was thinking of separating the land from the sea by means of e.g. filtering/reducing/masking, so that I could display them separately, without the colour gradient across the boundary. Another thing I tried was to upload a shapefile polygon of the land outline that I could use to clip the DEM, however (I believe the problem was) Norway has several different projection zones, so I had trouble uploading this as an asset.

Comment: Ok I have solved this now - I made a mask as you suggested, then mapped it over the image collection.

Comment: Great, please consider adding your solution as an answer so we can consider this question resolved.